# Get rows between last inserted and 10 minutes before that date

Tags: mysql

Could someone point me to right direction. I need to retrieve data from last inserted date to 10 minutes before that date.

this is my code, is there better way to write this?

```
SELECT Datum, Value
FROM tableX 
WHERE ItemFK = 109 
AND Datum BETWEEN 
DATE_SUB(
    (
        SELECT Datum 
        FROM tableX 
        WHERE ItemFK = 109 
        ORDER BY Datum DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
)
AND (
    SELECT Datum 
    FROM tableX 
    WHERE ItemFK = 109 
    ORDER BY Datum DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) 
ORDER BY Datum DESC
```

I can't use `DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND NOW()` as I don't know when was last time inserted.

Other way is by two queries. One to retreive last date, and other to get data from that date to 10 minutes before that date.

**EDIT**
Added SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c62c/1

Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: @Strawberry i just added sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM tblTable x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(datum) max_datum FROM tblTable ) y 
    ON x.datum >= y.max_datum - INTERVAL 10 minute;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c62c/18